# force:source:deploy: "Metadata API request failed: The deploy operation is missing a job ID. Initialize an operation with an ID, or start a new job"

Tags: salesforcedx

**Update (6/6/22)**: Just encountered this error again. I swear it comes back to taunt me every few months, then goes away just as randomly. Am I missing some documentation somewhere that explains what this means, or what I'm supposed to do? Since when do SFDX CLI commands involve an ID? Since when do I need to start a 'new job' to issue a `sfdx force:source:deploy` command? aaargh

---

Attempting to do deployments from SFDX. The same command line that worked just fine last night is now failing this morning.

Attempts such as

`sfdx force:source:deploy -c -p force-app/main/default`

or

`sfdx force:source:deploy -c -x package.xml`

return the same error:

`ERROR running force:source:deploy:  Metadata API request failed: The deploy operation is missing a job ID. Initialize an  operation with an ID, or start a new job.`

I can find no results on google explaining this error or what the fix is. Dev documentation doesn't show any sfdx commands related to initializing a job ID (I thought those were assigned automatically?), or starting a new job (I thought that's what running a new deployment command was?).

I ran the exact same command to the same org last night and it deployed successfully.

I updated SFDX to the latest version, no effect.

I can use the `sfdx force:source:retrieve` command successfully as well.

Anyone see this error before?

Comment: If you look for `~/.sfdx/stash.json` file - does it contain a jobId?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves there does not appear to be a `stash.json` file in that directory, just a `sfdx-config.json`

Comment: `sfdx-config.json` is in your repo directory. I'm talking about looking, if on windows, in your `C:\Users\YourUser\.sfdx` folder. I believe that file, `stash.json` is where the tool stores job Ids so was intrigued to see if you had it or if it had values.

Comment: ah thanks, found it.

`{
  "MDAPI_RETRIEVE": {
    "jobid": "09S03000001OOwpEAG",
    "retrievetargetdir": "C:\\Users\\smohyee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\sdx_sourceRetrieve_pkg_1623097891473"
  },
  "SOURCE_DEPLOY": {
    "jobid": "0Af0500000X8EKmCAN"
  }
}`

Comment: This is good to know about. I suppose I can use this to figure out the current job id and issue a cancel command the next time I run into this problem.

Comment: @smohyee this seems related to existing open issue [sfdx force:source:deploy issue using REST or SOAP](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1506), you might want to post a comment there to have further info

Answer (score 4):

I received this error b/c I recently refreshed my sandbox and forgot to reauthenticate my sfdx client for that org.  Once I reauthenticated, this fixed the error.

Comment: Same issue, same fix.

Answer (score 2):

This ended up resolving with running `sfdx update` and getting the latest version.

Comment: For anyone searching and finding this thread... I ran into this problem again at a later date and had a fully updated SFDX, so this probably wasn't related to whatever solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer the question but as I mentioned in the comments, it's worth noting that the error is closely related to an open issue reported on the GitHub repo:

[sfdx force:source:deploy issue using REST or SOAP](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1506)

For anyone else having the same error, followup the issue on GitHub to have latest update on the bug resolution

Answer (score 0):

@Mike - thank you! I had the same error message like described here and it drove me crazy. We had recently changed the myDomain and I assume that made a reauthentication needed - and changing the URL seems to cause this error message when deploying.